# Django - Creating my own CMS - advice on architecture

Tags: python, django, content-management-system

I was planning how I am going to architecture my CMS. And would like some advice:

The plan is that I will create a project called CMS. In that I will create an apps folder with various apps such as an admin module, blog module etc...

And for each new site I develop I will also create that as a new app within the project. So what this means is that each site/app I create will need its own database, will that be possible?

And secondly is this a good idea in general? Or should I create each new site as a new project.

I figured the above would be a good idea because then I can very easily reuse applications, across sites.

Thanks.

Comment: You should check out django-cms: https://www.django-cms.org/. While putting together a CMS is a good learning task, there is no point in reinventing the wheel and django-cms is very powerful and worth getting to grips with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear why do you need one application per site? There are 2 possibilities: if the only difference between sites is templates and static files then you do not need separate application for every site. If the difference is more global than that - you should not really combine these sites into one project but rather re-use common applications in many projects (one project per site).

As for the multiple databases - you can probably look at [Django's built-in sites framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/sites/); it does what you need within a single database.